# How can I find multiple text offset with multiple values?

Tags: vba, excel

The below code works great for one value, however, is there a way that I could do this for multiple values and finds?

```
Set Rng = Range("C1:B50").Find(What:="House", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

Rng.Offset(, -1).Value = "John"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through one or two arrays, passing the criteria and values into your code as the loop progresses.

```
Dim rng As Range, rang As Range, v As Long, vFINDs As Variant, vVALUs As Variant

vFINDs = Array("House", "Barn", "School")
vVALUs = Array("John", "Susan", "Bob")
Set rang = Range("C1:B50")

For v = LBound(vFINDs) To UBound(vFINDs)
    Set rng = rang.Find(what:=vFINDs(v), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Do While Not rng Is Nothing
        rng.Value = Chr(215) & rng.Value & Chr(215)
        rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = vVALUs(v)
        Set rng = rang.FindNext(after:=rng)
    Loop
    rang.Replace what:=Chr(215), replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart
Next v

Set rng = Nothing
Set rang = Nothing
```

*Addendum:* I've incorporated a `.FindNext` to loop through multiple matches. The problem with `.FindNext` is knowing just when to kick out of the loop or you will be repeatedly searching for *John* since you are not changing the original value. To cover that, I'm changing the value then removing the changes after-the-fact. The character I'm adding is ASCII 215 (e.g. × or the *times* symbol). I trust that adding or removing that symbol will not affect your data in any way.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, will this allow me to match each find to a value , for instance house = John , Barn = Susan , School = Bob etc

Comment: @user3512530 - If you keep the size of the arrays the same, then the `v` used as an increment will pull the matching pairs out of each at the same spot. e.g. if v=2 then vFINDs(v) is *School* and vVALUs(v) is *Bob* (these variant arrays are zero based).

Comment: the code works great however the data can change, not fixed , is there a way of matching the text regardless of where it is ?

E.g if I move duplicate house and flat the macro will match the values regardless of cell position?

Comment: @user3512530 - I'm afraid I really don't understand what you are asking here. If you want to change the terms of the question, then the original post should be altered or a new question posted.

Comment: Sorry I’ll make it clearer
If Column B contains duplicates of John I want the code to recognise this and fill opposite cell in Column A with the values stated e.g. House = John 
The code picks up the first string House but doesn’t apply it down to the rest 
Hope that makes sense, many thanks for your help

Comment: @user3512530 - Adjusted code with addition of `.FindNext`.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped I'll test out the new code later today